# When you are knocked unconscious while Net Running, do you drop out of your subgrid?

Tags: unconscious, cyberpunk-2020, netrunner

A runner took (physical) damage from a Hellbolt and failed their stun save--now they're unconscious.

Do they drop out of their subgrid, or are they still jacked in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally the software rendering you unconscious doesn't want to disconnect you, so that you can still be tracked via your connection. In fact, there are rules for attempts to jack out because of this. Ruling that being rendered unconscious allows one to, effectively, automatically jack out would make being knocked out intentionally a good fallback strategy for runners: someone friendly could be standing next to you and stun you in order to get you out of the net quick so you can avoid being tracked by security teams.

My textual support for this is based on the Spanish version, so the page numbering is possibly different depending on what language your book is in (I would use the chapters and section names as a guide):

In the section **THE MENU** the book says that for logging out you must **roll an 8 or less on 1D10**, so it is not something as easy as removing your jack-- it could be harmful (as everything in CP2020 this is very vague leaving this things up to the DM), and this supports the fact that if you are stunned you cant make the Log Out command from the menu and thus you would still be logged in.

**Hellbolt**, as described in the program list, is the same as the **Stun** program but with damage (1D6) added: you must roll for stun and death saves. If we read the **Stun** program it says that it is designed to **freeze you in place for 1D6 turns** and that it is **very popular among the Netcops**, so this points to the fact you are not disconnected, since if it disconnected you when you were stunned you would become *harder* not *easier* to track down.

On the **Security Level**s of the **LDL** link you have to roll and on results 1-4, and 5 your connection is "cut" but is not clear what "cut" means; this could be read as "disconnected", but somehow on 5 result Netcops find out your "access code" and you can have a "friendly visit on real space".

The game relies heavily on the description of the programs, if you read the section for create your own programs the category of a **Hellbolt** is **Antipersonal**, and its described as **this function Attack and kill Netrunners. Runner is killed (receive damage) expelled or lobotomized**, so you can make a version that expels Netrunners out of the net if you say so, but is up to the program creator.

Once again, the wording may differ from the English version

Comment: As I said on other CP2020 responses, the RAW are very hard to use and every gaming table has his own interpretation of what is written.  Hard to find a definitive answer as in other games is clear what happens with such states so common as "stunned"

Comment: Netcops can find you even after you disconnect/are disconnected as long as they have got enough information on you before you cut the connection.  I mention this because you seem to think that a roll of 5 for accessing a secure node is weird in that Netcops can find you but actually they just get your access code before they kick you out.

Comment: The weird thing is that most things are loosely explained and most things are very random (LDL jumping is just sheer luck), just that.